# Como personalizar a seta de um select

Tags: javascript, css, select

Tenho uma tabela de preços, nela tem um `select` para a pessoa escolher o ciclo de pagamento como mostrado na imagem:

[image]
 sendo que eu fiz com CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance:none; 
background:#E9E9E9 url("../imagens/bgs/seta.png") 95.5% 50% no-repeat;
```

Como mostra nessa imagem só funciona no Google Chrome:

[image]
 gostaria de fazer igual da segunda imagem e que funcionasse em todos os navegadores, talvez tenha como fazer com JavaScript?

Answer (score 7):

Infelizmente ainda não é possível fazer isto da "maneira certa" em todos os browsers, uma vez que a propriedade `appearance` não é onipresente.

**Suporte dos navegadores atuais:**
[image: Browser Support]

Por hora, é importantíssimo manter um *fallback*, mas você pode aumentar o suporte adicionando também o prefixo `-moz`.

```css
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance:    none;
appearance:         none;
```

---

Alguns desenvolvedores englobam a tag `select` dentro de uma `div` e a estilizam, como no exemplo:

```html
<div class="select">
  <select>
    ...
  </select>
</div>
```

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:    none;
  appearance:         none;
  width: 100%;
}

.select {
  ...
  background: #e9e9e9 url('../imagens/bgs/seta.png') 95.5% 50% no-repeat;
  ...
}
```

Este método pode aumentar a compatibilidade, embora ainda não seja uma solução *cross-browser*.

---

Ou, utilize uma biblioteca JavaScript como a [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Comment: Interessante, eu não conhecia isso. Mas pelo que vi na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance), parece que essa propriedade foi cortada dos rascunhos da especificação, então dificilmente será cross-browser um dia.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Você tem razão, esta especificação é conhecida como **System Appearance** e foi proposta no **CSSS3-UI Candidate Recommendation** em 11/05/2004, mas nunca saiu do papel. É bem improvável que a propriedade `appearance` esteja presente no **CSS4-UI** da maneira que conhecemos hoje, a realidade é que dez anos de se passaram, muitos componentes (principalmente formulários) foram adicionados no HTML5 e isso deixa clara a necessidade do reenquadramento e reexploração dos problemas que originalmente fora projetado para resolver.